# gcc c++ coroutine runs avx SIMD code, but causes SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, avx, c++-coroutine

c++ coroutine runs avx SIMD code, but causes SIGSEGV for AVX2 and AVX512

```
#define AVX512 0
#define AVX2 1
#define SSE 0

HelloCoroutine hello(int& index, int id, int group_size) {
    unsigned res=0;
#if AVX512
// g++ simd.cpp -std=gnu++20 -fcoroutines -O2 -march=skylake -mavx512f
// segment fault
    for(auto i= index++; i< 20; i=index++)
    {
        std::cout <<"step 1" <<std::endl;
        __m512i v_offset = _mm512_set1_epi64(int64_t (i));
        std::cout <<"step 2" <<std::endl;
        __m512i v_size = _mm512_set1_epi64(int64_t(group_size));
        std::cout <<"step 3" <<std::endl;
        res = _mm512_cmpgt_epi64_mask(v_offset, v_size);
        cout <<i << " > " << group_size <<" ? " << (int)res<<endl;
        co_await std::suspend_always();
    }
#elif AVX2 
// g++ simd.cpp -std=gnu++20 -fcoroutines -O2 -march=skylake
// only specify `-O2 -march=skylake` and runs ok on local machine, otherwise segment fault (also on godbolt)
    for(auto i= index++; i< 20; i=index++)
    {
        std::cout <<"step 1" <<std::endl;
        __m256i v_offset = _mm256_set1_epi32(int32_t (i));
        std::cout <<"step 2" <<std::endl;
        __m256i v_size = _mm256_set1_epi32(int32_t(group_size));
        std::cout <<"step 3" <<std::endl;
        res = _mm256_movemask_epi8(_mm256_cmpgt_epi32(v_offset, v_size));
        cout <<i << " > " << group_size <<" ? " << (int)res<<endl;
        co_await std::suspend_always();
    }
#elif SSE
    for(auto i= index++; i< 20; i=index++)
    {
        __m128i v_offset = _mm_set1_epi32(int32_t (i));
        __m128i v_size = _mm_set1_epi32(int32_t(group_size));
        res = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpgt_epi32(v_offset, v_size));
        cout <<i << " > " << group_size <<" ? " << res<<endl;
        co_await std::suspend_always();
    }    
#else
    for(auto i= index++; i< 20; i=index++)
    {
        res = i > group_size;
        cout <<i << " > " << group_size <<" ? " << res<<endl;
        co_await std::suspend_always();
    }
#endif
}
```

compile at https://godbolt.org/z/h3hej1ddq

-std=c++20 -fcoroutines  -mbmi2 -mavx  -mavx512f -mavx512pf -mavx512er -mavx512cd -mavx512vl

but result error for avx and avx512, only SSE works OK

Program returned: 139
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV
step 1

but it works on on clang-16 `-std=gnu++20 -O2 -march=skylake -mavx512f` https://godbolt.org/z/nMfbn8G9T

Comment: The outer `ifdef` is confusing.  I only just realized that the vector stuff is *inside* a loop that does `co_await std::suspend_always();`, that's not a separate loop after like it looks like.  That makes more sense to explain why GCC is keeping vector locals in coroutine storage pointed-to by RBX instead of on the stack.

Comment: `clang++ -std=gnu++20 -O2 -march=native` makes a working program on my AVX2 system, but only because it optimized the vectors down to 128-bit or scalar.  Without `-O2` (so the default `-O0`), it also makes a segfaulting program.

Comment: Are you running this on a CPU that supports those instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a GCC bug, unless coroutines are documented to not support local variables with `alignof(T) > alignof(max_align_t)`  (Such as `__m256i` or `__m512i`).

You can report it (preferably with a minimal AVX2 test case) to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

With a version that only requires AVX2 instead of AVX-512, I could test it on my desktop and see it faults on `vmovdqa YMMWORD PTR [rbx+0x40],ymm0` which requires 32-byte alignment.  (Storing the result of a `vpbroadcastd`, initializing `__m256i v_offset = set1...`.)  (https://godbolt.org/z/8vfz3v5v1 just fixes the `__m256i` block, compiles with `-std=gnu++20 -fcoroutines -O2 -march=skylake`)

IDK why it's using RBX to access locals instead of RSP; I guess that's how coroutines work in the `hello(hello(int&, int, int)::_Z5helloRiii.Frame*) [clone .actor]:` version of the function.  In that coroutine version, GCC still just aligns the stack pointer with  `and  rsp, -32` / `sub rsp, 192`, but that doesn't help for things stored relative to RBX.

---

Note that all 3 of your versions require AVX-512, just with different vector widths. Compare-into-mask like `_mm_cmpgt_epi32_mask` always requires AVX-512.

If you want an integer mask with AVX2 or SSE, you need `_mm_cmpgt_epi32` and `_mm_movemask_epi8` (1 bit per byte) or `_mm_movemask_ps( _mm_castsi128_ps(cmp_result) )` (1 bit per int32), or the `_mm256` equivalent.

Use `-march=native` or `-march=skylake-avx512`, `-march=znver4`, or whatever. No real CPUs have ever supported both AVX512ER (Xeon Phi) and AVX512VL (everything else). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512

If your CPU didn't support AVX-512, you'd get SIGILL (on all 3), not SIGSEGV.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I reported it to gcc https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110967